# Error when include path_provider

Tags: android, flutter

I get an error when I'm trying to compile path_provider:

> /home/user/projects/flutterframework/TestApp/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/PluginRegistry.java:15:
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>
> path_provider = PathProviderPlugin.register(activity);
>
> symbol: method register(FlutterActivity)
>
> location: class PathProviderPlugin
>
> 1 error
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

How can I fix it?
Lubuntu 16 LTS x64

Comment: can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have an old project template. You shouldn't have a PluginRegistry.java. Try flutter upgrade, recreate your project and copy the old project's dart files and assets over.